# Question on adding value in an array to another array for counting c++

Tags: c++, arrays, design-patterns, probability, counting

Here's the situation:

User can choose up to 4 dices on the table with a range[1-12] faces they want (Yes, 1 face dice is a THING here). Then the program will calculate all the outcome possibilities.

For example: 2 dices, 1st with 6 faces, 2nd with 2 faces.

Output:

Sum of 2 = 1

Sum of 3 = 2

Sum of 4 = 2

Sum of 5 = 2

Sum of 6 = 2

Sum of 7 = 2

Sum of 8 = 1

I have found out the pattern to calculate with all of the possibilities with different of no. of dices and faces they have, here's the illustration:

4 dices with faces [6, 2, 3, 4] respectively

[Click here to check the pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqKV7.png)

Blue area is a dice with 6 faces
Green area is 6 faces with 2 times
Yellow area is green area loop with 3 times
Read area is yellow area loop with 4 times

The numbers aside are the count of the appearance of each sum and it's correct all the time no matter what inputs are.

Every new area will be start at id[5] and after every iteration the process area will shift [i+1] space untill the end.

However, I've attempted many times and still cannot find the correct way to implement this pattern into c++ program.

My codes are like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int num, face, faceCounter;
  int faces[15] = { 0 }, counter1[150] = { 0 }, tempCount[150] = { 0 };

  cout << "How many dices: ";
  cin >> num;

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        cout << "Face for dice number: " << i;
        cin >> face;

        faces[i] = face;           //Store number of face into each dice
        faceCounter += face;       // Store how many outputs needed
    }

  // Calculate the first iteration of dices

  for (int k = 0; k < faces[2]; k++) {
        for (int j = num + k; j < (num + faces[1] + k); j++) {
            tempCount[j]++;
        }
    }

    // Copy results into counter1[]

    for (int i = num; i <= faceCounter; i++) {
        counter1[i] += tempCount[i];
    }

    // Find out the remaining dices

    for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < faces[i+1]; k++) {                          // Calculate the count range
            for (int j = num + k + 1; j < (num + faces[i] + k); j++) {  // Add the previous counter's value into temp counter
                tempCount[j] += counter1[i];
            }
            if (k == faces[i + 1] - 1)                                  // Make sure finished the for loop first then to final addition, won't duplicate data
                finished = 1;
        }

        //Load results back to counter, which will using it back in loop for further counting

        for (int i = num; (i <= faceCounter) && (finished = 1); i++) {
            counter1[i] += tempCount[i];
        }

        finished = 0;
    }

    for (int i = num; i <= faceCounter; i++) {
        cout << "Sum of " << i << " = " << counter1[i] << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This is not working though.

My desired output is:

```
Sum of 4 = 1
Sum of 5 = 4
Sum of 6 = 9
Sum of 7 = 15
Sum of 8 = 20
Sum of 9 = 23
Sum of 10 = 23
Sum of 11 = 20
Sum of 12 = 15
Sum of 13 = 9
Sum of 14 = 4
Sum of 15 = 1
```

How can I change it?

Comment: Think recursion.

Comment: Please add a main and includes, + desired output for given input. That would be a good moment to structure your routine into a clean function.

Comment: I thought about recursion, but what is the base case's return value?

Comment: @Superlokkus Sorry for the inconvenience, I have already updated the code and the desired output is also updated on the post.

Comment: I don't really follow the implementation you posted. Anyway if you are getting sufficiently frustrated with that, I have two ideas to try. (1) Brute force: enumerate all the combinations of the various dice; there are n1 times n2 times n3 times ... number of combinations. Then add up each combination. Now for each distinct value of the sums of combinations, count up how many combinations there are which have that sum. A hash table is a convenient way to track that. Finally output the distinct values of the sums and associated counts.

Comment: (2) Adding up dice faces can be calculated exactly as the convolution of arrays of the form `[1, 1, 1, ...]` which have number of elements equal to the number of faces and all elements equal to 1. The convolution of two arrays is a simple summation. Create a function named `conv`, construct your arrays, then just say `conv(dn, conv(d(n-1), conv(d(n-2), ... conv(d2, d1))))`. You can try that in Octave, for example, to see how it works out.